# MessageEmbed field values may not be empty discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I know this is probably a simple question, but I literally just upgraded to discord.js v13 today and I am a bit confused as to how some of the things work. I have been having trouble with a serverinfo command that worked on v12. I will provide some of the code to help.

error logs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTTE0.jpg

serverinfo code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const moment = require('moment');

const filterLevels = {
    DISABLED: 'Off',
    MEMBERS_WITHOUT_ROLES: 'No Role',
    ALL_MEMBERS: 'Everyone'
};

const verificationLevels = {
    NONE: 'None',
    LOW: 'Low',
    MEDIUM: 'Medium',
    HIGH: '(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻',
    VERY_HIGH: '┻━┻ ﾐヽ(ಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻'
};

const regions = {
    brazil: 'Brazil',
    europe: 'Europe',
    hongkong: 'Hong Kong',
    india: 'India',
    japan: 'Japan',
    russia: 'Russia',
    singapore: 'Singapore',
    southafrica: 'South Africa',
    sydeny: 'Sydeny',
    'us-central': 'US Central',
    'us-east': 'US East',
    'us-west': 'US West',
    'us-south': 'US South'
};

module.exports = {
    name: "serverinfo",
    aliases: ['si', 'sinfo'],
    category: "info",
    description: "shows the information of the server",
    usage: "[command | alias]",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        
    const owner = await message.guild.fetchOwner();
    
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#724e72')
    .setTitle('Server Info')
    .setAuthor(`${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
    .setDescription('shows information about the server')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/MafwgxK.png')
    .addField('General', [
                `**Name:** ${message.guild.name}`,
                //`**ID:** ${message.guild.id}`,
                `**Owner:** ${owner.user.tag}`,
                `**Region:** ${regions[message.guild.region]}`,
                `**Boost Tier:** ${message.guild.premiumTier ? `Tier ${message.guild.premiumTier}` : 'None'}`,
                `**Explicit Filter:** ${filterLevels[message.guild.explicitContentFilter]}`,
                `**Verification Level:** ${verificationLevels[message.guild.verificationLevel]}`,
                `**Time Created:** ${moment(message.guild.createdTimestamp).format('LT')} ${moment(message.guild.createdTimestamp).format('LL')} [${moment(message.guild.createdTimestamp).fromNow()}]`,
                '\u200b'
            ])
            .addField('Statistics', [
                `**Role Count:** ${message.guild.roles.cache.size}`,
                `**Emoji Count:** ${message.guild.emojis.cache.size}`,
                //`**Regular Emoji Count:** ${emojis.filter(emoji => !emoji.animated).size}`,
                //`**Animated Emoji Count:** ${emojis.filter(emoji => emoji.animated).size}`,
                `**Member Count:** ${message.guild.memberCount}`,
                `**Humans:** ${message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size}`,
                `**Bots:** ${message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).size}`,
                `**Text Channels:** ${message.guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type === 'text').size}`,
                `**Voice Channels:** ${message.guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type === 'voice').size}`,
                `**Boost Count:** ${message.guild.premiumSubscriptionCount || '0'}`,
                '\u200b'
            ])
            .addField('Presence', [
                `**Online:** ${message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'online').size}`,
                `**Idle:** ${message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'idle').size}`,
                `**Do Not Disturb:** ${message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'dnd').size}`,
                `**Offline:** ${message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'offline').size}`,
                '\u200b'
            ])
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('a')
    
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
        
       }
}
```

command handler (if needed idk):

```
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");

const ascii = require("ascii-table");

let table = new ascii("Commands");
table.setHeading("Command", "Load status");

module.exports = (client) => {
    readdirSync("./commands/").forEach(dir => {
        const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
    
        for (let file of commands) {
            let pull = require(`../commands/${dir}/${file}`);
    
            if (pull.name) {
                client.commands.set(pull.name, pull);
                table.addRow(file, 'Working');
            } else {
                table.addRow(file, `❌  -> missing a help.name, or help.name is not a string.`);
                continue;
            }
    
            if (pull.aliases && Array.isArray(pull.aliases)) pull.aliases.forEach(alias => client.aliases.set(alias, pull.name));
        }
    });
    
    console.log(table.toString());
}
```

messageCreate event

```
const del = require('../../functions.js');
const Levels = require('discord-xp');
require('dotenv').config();
const prefix = process.env.PREFIX;

module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {
    
    if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;
    
    const randomXP = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14) + 1; //1-15
    const hasLeveledUP = await Levels.appendXp(message.author.id, message.guild.id, randomXP);
    if (hasLeveledUP) {
        const user = await Levels.fetch(message.author.id, message.guild.id);
        message.channel.send(`${message.member} is now level ${user.level}.`);
    }
    
    
    //const args = message.content.startsWith(prefix) ? message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g) : message.content.replace(/[^\s]*/, '').trim().split(/ +/g);
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
    if (cmd.length === 0) return;
    
    let command = client.commands.get(cmd);
    if (!command) command = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd));
    
    if (command) {
        command.run(client, message, args);
    }
}
```

index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { Collection, Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const Levels = require('discord-xp');
require('dotenv').config();

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS] }); //name of bot
const mongoose = require('./database/mongoose.js');

Levels.setURL(`PASS`);
['aliases', 'commands'].forEach(x => client[x] = new Collection());
['command', 'event'].forEach(x => require(`./handlers/${x}`)(client));

mongoose.init();
client.login(process.env.CLIENT_TOKEN); // SECRET TOKEN
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like .addField does not allow string arrays for the second argument. You may need to combine the string array into one string.

You can see the documentation for .addField here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addField